# Plot in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a simple vortex in cylindrical coordinates give by

$v_{\phi} = \frac{\Gamma}{2 \pi r}$

Is there an alternative method to plot this than, for example, using streamplot and converting r and the cylindrical unit vector $\vec{\phi}$ to cartesian rectangular coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried `PolarPlot[]`?

Comment: What you describe is how I would do it. I don't think there is another method because your goal is to illustrate vectors, so that `PolarPlot` won't work.