# StreamPlot in Polar Coordinates

Tags: plotting

I want to use StreamPlot to map out the field lines of an electric field $\mathbf{E}$ given by
$$
\mathbf{E} = \frac{3D}{4r^{4}}(3\cos(\theta)^{2}-1)\mathbf{\hat{r}} +\frac{3D}{4r^{4}}\sin(2\theta)\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}
$$
I could convert it to Cartesian coordinates, but I have quite a few more fields to plot, so I would rather leave it in polar coordinates. How can I get StreamPlot to accept polar coordinates?

Comment: Just use the function! You will get the stream lines in the $r-\theta$ space!

Comment: possible duplicate with no answers : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18550/plot-in-cylindrical-coordinates

Comment: Thanks Andre, although the other one was posted first, I've marked it as the duplicate and this one as the canonical version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do it is to write our own wrapper function which does the conversion and feeds it to `StreamPlot`. Thereby we have the convenience of a selfcontained function without the hassle of having to do the conversion manually every time. We can convert our field

```
field =  3/(4r^4) (3Cos[\[Theta]]^2-1) OverHat[r]
       + 3/(4r^4) Sin[2\[Theta]] OverHat[\[Theta]]
```

[image: Field]

to cartesian form by preparing a set of conversion rules from polar to cartesian coordinates

```
tocartesian = {OverHat[r] -> x/r OverHat[x] + y/r OverHat[y],
               OverHat[\[Theta]] -> -(y/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]) OverHat[x]+x/Sqrt[x^2+y^2] OverHat[y],
               r -> Sqrt[x^2+y^2],
               \[Theta] -> ArcTan[x,y] };
```

and a rule to make this into a list afterwards

```
cartesianlist = (a_ OverHat[x] + b_ OverHat[y]) -> {a, b};
```

Then we can let Mathematica repeatedly apply (`//.`) our `tocartesian` rule to eliminate all occurences of `r` and then let `FullSimplify` help us to eliminate the trigonometric functions. At last we use `cartesianlist` to switch to list form:

```
cartesianfield = FullSimplify[field //. tocartesian] /. cartesianlist
```

[image: Cartesian form of the field]

For convenient usage we define our own `PolarStreamPlot` function

```
PolarStreamPlot[{rfield_,thetafield_}, opts___] := Module[
  {tocartesian,cartesianlist,field,cartesianfield},
  tocartesian={OverHat[r]->x/r OverHat[x]+y/r OverHat[y],
               OverHat[\[Theta]]->-(y/Sqrt[x^2+y^2])OverHat[x]
                                        + x/Sqrt[x^2+y^2] OverHat[y],
               r->Sqrt[x^2+y^2], \[Theta]->ArcTan[x,y]};
  cartesianlist=(a_ OverHat[x] + b_ OverHat[y])->{a,b};
  field = rfield OverHat[r] + thetafield OverHat[\[Theta]];
  cartesianfield = FullSimplify[field//.tocartesian]/.cartesianlist;
  StreamPlot[cartesianfield, opts]
]
```

and now we can feed it our original $r$-$\theta$ field definition directly

```
PolarStreamPlot[
  {3/(4r^4) (3Cos[\[Theta]]^2-1),
   3/(4r^4) Sin[2\[Theta]]},
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
]
```

[image: StreamPlot]

Comment: `TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", field, {r, θ} -> {x, y}]` will also do the conversion for you, if `field = {3/(4 r^4) (3 Cos[θ]^2 - 1), 3/(4 r^4) Sin[2 θ]}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 one up for v9!!!!

Comment: The `Overscript[r, ^]` in the code needs to be changed to `OverHat[r]`, otherwise it will result in an error.

Answer (score 15):

If you have version 9, the `TransformedField` as mentioned by MichaelE2 is the way to go. In version 8, the analogous thing (which can also still be used in version 9), is this:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Clear[field, r, θ, ϕ];
m = Transpose[
     Transpose[JacobianMatrix[#, Spherical @@ #]]/
      ScaleFactors[Spherical @@ #]] &@{r, θ, ϕ};
field[r_, θ_, ϕ_] = 
  Simplify[m.{3/(4 r^4) (3 Cos[θ]^2 - 1), 
     3/(4 r^4) Sin[2 θ], 0}];

StreamPlot[
 Delete[
  field @@ CoordinatesFromCartesian[{x, 0, z}, Spherical], 2], 
  {x, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}]
```

[image: stream plot]

It uses the `VectorAnalysis` package like Spawn's answer, but I didn't see any reason why you would first plot the function in polar coordinates, so I inserted the coordinate transformation directly in the `StreamPlot`. This works for any field defined as a function (`field`) of the three spherical coordinates, as shown above. All you need is to replace `field` by `field @@ CoordinatesFromCartesian[{x, y, z}, Spherical]`. In the plot here, I just set `y=0` to get the field lines in the `x-z` plane.

**Edit**

The field in the question was given in spherical coordinates, but I copied it from a comment and assumed it was cartesian components. So to correct that, in the definition of `field`, I added the transformation to the spherical unit vectors. I did this in the most general way I could think of, so that the `field` can be changed easily. All that you need is the transformation matrix `m`. If you desire any other coordinate system, just replace `Spherical` above.

The definition of `field` also is kept three-dimensional for generality, so that in the `StreamPlot` I have to `Delete` one of the three components. Since I'm plotting the `x-z` plane, I drop the `y` component which is zero there.

Comment: The field is given in polar space ($\hat r, \hat\theta$), so first of all you have to change the base of the tangent space. Then you have to consider the transformations involved. For spherical coordinates the change is$$r=\sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2),\\
\theta=\arccos(z/r),\\
\phi=\arctan(y/x),
$$ for cylindrical $$
r=\sqrt(x^2+y^2),\\
\theta=\arctan(y/x),\\
z=z
$$ To coincide you have to set z=0 and use the first and the third argument. Cylindrical coordinates are better because they are just the  cartesian product of polar space with the Real line.

Comment: What i did was to first create the stream plot in polar space and then transform the whole plot in cartesian ones. It is evident from your plot that something is wrong though ... Nevertheless v9 comes to the rescue!!

Comment: Oh yes, I overlooked that part. I'll edit my answer to fix it usng the same method I used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14362/245).

Answer (score 12):

**Update - A straightforward alternative**

Just to put my comment into code in at least one answer:  For V9+,

```
field = {3/(4 r^4) (3 Cos[θ]^2 - 1), 3/(4 r^4) Sin[2 θ]};
StreamPlot[Evaluate@TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
   field, {r, θ} -> {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
(*  image as above  *)
```

---

**Original approach**

Here is an approach I have been taking with my differential equations class.  It shows some of the versatility of the `Dt` operator and we can break the process down into elementary mathematical steps, instead of using `TransformedField` as a black box, although using `Dt` to handle the calculus.  We can represent $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ by `Dt[r]` and `r Dt[θ]`.  Then straight substitutions may be used.  In the end we can convert to a vector field by replacing `Dt[x]`, `Dt[y]` by `{1, 0}`, `{0, 1}` respectively.

```
polarToCartesian = {r -> Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], θ -> ArcTan[x, y]};
differentialTofield = {Dt[x] -> {1, 0}, Dt[y] -> {0, 1}};

field = (3/(4 r^4) (3 Cos[θ]^2 - 1)) Dt[r] + (3/(4 r^4) Sin[2 θ]) r Dt[θ];

cartesianField = 
 field /. polarToCartesian /. differentialTofield // Simplify
(*
  { (3 x ( 2 x^2 - 3 y^2)) / (4 (x^2 + y^2)^(7/2)),
   -(3 y (-4 x^2 +   y^2)) / (4 (x^2 + y^2)^(7/2))}
*)

StreamPlot[
 cartesianField,
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Answer (score 4):

Ok the stream plot on the polar space is given by say

```
With[{D=1},plot=StreamPlot[{3*D/(4r^4)(3Cos[θ]^2-1),3*D/(4r^4) Sin[2θ]},{r,0,1},{θ,0,2*π},
     StreamScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, x]}]]
```

Now, IF you want this stream plot *embedded* on cartesian space you can either transform the vector field to cartesian space as you correctly say or do the following:

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Show[plot/.
Arrow[v:{__?VectorQ}]:>Arrow[(Most[CoordinatesToCartesian[Append[#, 0], Cylindrical]]&/@v)], 
PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

I suppose your question is if there is a function like `PolarPlot` for StreamPlot or other plot functions. The short answer is no. You can either change before hand the function or the field or embed the field afterward. Which method is best depends on the specific trasformation involved and if you want to exploit Mathematica's routines in giving you the best presentation of the field.

Comment: It works (+1), but I  had to correct a small syntax error  in `StreamScale` where a `}` is missing.

Comment: @Jens thanx! I am correcting it now!

Answer (score 4):

For those using Mathematica 9, I have created the following function to produce polar plots.  It takes all options that can be given to StreamPlot, but also masks any results outside of the provided domain (which is provided in polar coordinates).

```
SetAttributes[PolarStreamPlot, HoldAll];
PolarStreamPlot[
  fns_, {r_Symbol, rMin_, rMax_}, {t_Symbol, tMin_, tMax_}, opts___] :=
  Module[{Fns, x, y, RF, TMin, TMax, mArcTan, RMax},
  If[rMin >= rMax,
   Throw["Invalid range for r!"]
   ];
  If[tMin >= tMax || tMax - tMin > 2 Pi,
   Throw["Invalid range for \[Theta]!"]
   ];
  TMin = Mod[tMin, 2 Pi, tMin];
  TMax = Mod[tMax, 2 Pi, tMin];
  If[TMax == TMin, TMax += 2 Pi];
  mArcTan[vars__] = Mod[ArcTan[vars], 2 Pi, TMin];
  Fns = TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
     fns, {r, t} -> {x, y}] /. ArcTan -> mArcTan;
  RMax = rMax;
  StreamPlot[Fns, {x, -RMax, RMax}, {y, -RMax, RMax}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y}, 
     Evaluate[
      mArcTan[x, y] <= TMax && rMin <= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= rMax]], opts]
  ]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can consider using `Block` to localize `r` and `t` so the function will still work when these have a value.  Also, you can use Message and Return instead of Throw.  An uncaught Throw is technically a runtime error.  Finally, `Evaluate` only works when it's at level 1 within a held function.  I'm not sure it's necessary here.

Comment: To force a single evaluation of `rMax`, use an additional Module variable, say `rMax2` and assign `rMax2 = rMax`. Then use `rMax2` in StreamPlot.

Comment: @Szabolcs  With regard to putting `r` and `t` in a `Block`, isn't this already happening since they're arguments of the function? (Sorry, I'm a CS guy - not so used to Mathematica)

Comment: There's the line starting with `Fns = ...`.  It has `{r,t}`.  This will effectively evaluate the symbols that were passed to `PolarStreamPlot` as $r$ and $t$.  If they have values, it will cause an error in `TransformedField`.  Try setting `r=1` then calling `PolarStreamPlot[..., {r, ...}, ...]`. It will show errors.    However, if you wrap the whole thing in `Block[{r,t}, ...]` then it'll work.  Do not mind about the red colouring you see, it's just a warning.  But doing this here is justified.

Comment: Another potential localization failure is not using `:=` in the definition of `mArcTan`.  However, for reasons that I don't understand, Mathematica does rename `vars` to localize it, so having a globally defined `vars=1` does not actually break things.

Comment: How about some more improvement [like this](http://pastebin.com/2WTiDgQ4)?  I'm also uneasy about the `Evaluate` in `Function` which should break if `x` has a value, but *it doesn't break* and I don't understand why ...

Comment: Let me illustrate: `x = 1;
Module[{z},
 Function[x, Evaluate[x < y]]
 ]`.  Here things go wrong because the value of the (global) `x` is substituted in.  It makes no difference if `x` is localized in the `Module`, it won't affect `Function`.  If this is what happens in your function too, it would break if `x` or `y` have a global value.  But yours is *slightly* different.  Consider now `x = 1;
Module[{z},
 Function[x, Evaluate[x < z]]
 ]`.  For some reason Mma decides to rename `x` when it occurs together with the `Module` variable, which *accidentally* protects it here ...

Comment: For this reason I'd remove that `Evaluate` and give up some performance for the piece of mind that this'll work even in future or past versions where renaming might act differently.