# How to plot trajectory for a differential equation in polar coordinates?

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, plotting

I have a differential equation for dr/dt and d[Theta]/dt in terms of r and theta, and I am trying to plot the trajectory in the x-y plane for a given initial condition (r,theta).

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html

There is an example on this page for a set of differential equations already in cartesian coordinates, but I don't know what to do for polar.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please provide your equations in the question, so readers know what problem you are trying to solve.  For instance, I would think you should use ParametricPlot, not StreamPlot.

Comment: duplicate for field: [StreamPlot in Polar Coordinates](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23034/5478), answer for single trajectory: [graph in the Polar Plane](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67261/5478). `TransformedField` may be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define:

```
 polarToCartesian[r_,theta_]:=r*{Cos[theta],Sin[theta]}
```

Then, after you solve the differential equation, use `ParametricPlot`:

```
 ParametricPlot[polarToCartesian[r[t],theta[t]],{t,0,t0}]
```

**UPDATE**

```
polarToCartesian[{r_, theta_}] := r*{Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}

s = ParametricNDSolve[
      {r'[t] == r[t] (1 - (r[t])^2) (4 - (r[t])^2), 
       theta'[t] == 2 - (r[t])^2,
       r[0] == r0, theta[0] == theta0},
       {r, theta}, {t, 0, 10}, {r0, theta0}];


solution[r0_, theta0_, t_] := 
 Evaluate[{r[r0, theta0][t], theta[r0, theta0][t]} /. s]

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[polarToCartesian[solution[r0, theta0, t]], {t, 0, 10},
   PlotRange -> {-2.5, 2.5}]
   ,{r0, 0.01, 2}, {theta0, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: could you please try plotting my example? It seems to keep running and won't display anything for me, I think it's having trouble trying to solve the equations. My differential equations are r'[t] == r[t] (1 - (r[t])^2) (4 - (r[t])^2), \[Theta]'[t] == 2 - (r[t])^2

Comment: @KennyL You should add this important information to your question.

Comment: @KennyL : Done!